# how can i manipulate dom in a cross domain window popup by window.open()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

I wanna let the extension to help me check the status of different website. So I need the extension to open different website and check some dom in the webpage. The website may be a dynamic web page so i have to load the page in the browser so that i can get the real dom (not just the source).
Usually, for same domain circumstence. It may be like this:

```
var w = window.open('http://www.yahoo.com');
console.log(w);
$(w).bind('load', function() {
  //In chrome extension, i can not get "this.document"
  //And in iframe i can not get "document", either
  console.log(this.document);
});
```

I am trying to use the chrome extension's permission for domain-cross ajax. So i can manipulate the window from different domians.
But it failed. The snippet does not work under a chrome extension. Why? Why chrome extension have the permission to do cross-domain ajax but cannot manipulate window from other domain?
And I also tried the iframe. It doesn't work, either.

I wanna ask that is there some way to manipulate cross domain document manipulate by chrome or chrome extension?

Comment: "I wanna let the extension to help me check the status of different website" ... my interpretation of that statement is that this extension is for your own personal use. Do you mean that you want it to allow the user of the extension to check another website, or is this something you only need to work for yourself?

Comment: @GGG You answer can help me to finish the app for my own. But I also hope my app to be used by other people. But I dont know if it is possible.

Comment: Ok, I then I misunderstood you. I've deleted my answer.

Comment: @GGG But your answer is also quite helpful for me. I never know that chrome can have some open mode. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One advantage of chrome extension is: it grants more rights for webapp to bypass some security restriction, which include XHR.

Please check the document on cross-site xhr:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html

some precaution:

1. You need to config the `manifest.json` file, `permissions` properties to enable xhr on more urls: 
   [More possible permissions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions)
   If you need the extension content script run in iframe, please notice the extra properties set in `content_scripts` [doc](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html)

   > ```
   > {
   >    "name": "My extension",
   >    ...
   >    "permissions": [   
   >            "tabs",
   >            "http://*/*",
   >            "https://*/*" ],
   >    "content_scripts": [{ //note: for iframe, array
   >        "matches":[
   >            "http://*/*",
   >            "https://*/*" //match all url
   >        ],
   >        "run_at": "document_idle",
   >        "js": ["jquery.min.js", "contentscript.js"] //script you need to run in iframe
   >     }]
   > ```
   >
   > }
2. You need to handle the xhr in `background.html`, or you pass the url to the new window that extension will open (by `chrome.windows.create`). You may get some idea on the extension that I am working on (for manifest and window open): https://github.com/vincicat/ImageInfoPlus

Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried to write permissions like this.`"permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]`. But it can not give me the permission to get the window by window.open funciton. And so is the iframe's window permission. But I have found an api **chrome.tabs.executeScript**. This may help me, I have not tried it yet.

Comment: 1. open new window you need to use `chrome.windows.create`, not `window.open`; 

2. for `iframe` script, you need to do something extra: set `"all_frames":true` in `content_scripts` - especially want to use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` you may need that too.

I will update my answer, see will it works.

Comment: OK, I have accepted your answer. Thanks for helping me so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can run chrome with the `--disable-web-security` argument to disable the cross-domain policy. If you do this, you won't need an extension to manipulate the other window.

Comment: `--disable-web-security` should be avoided for general purpose browsing and only used when explicitly testing something that needs.

Comment: @abraham my understanding of the question was that he's making a chrome extension for his own use, to get around the same-origin policy. I was offering him another option. Either way, the question is clearly not about general-purpose browsing.